# Get text when copying from input

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="text"> event: <span id="result"></span>
<script>
var input = document.body.children[0];

 input.oncopy  = function(e) {
    debugger
  e = e || event;
 // document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = e.type +' '+input.value;
 // return false;
}
```

I want get text when copying .It is possible?

Comment: Why is this not working? It should do. You could also try `e.target.value`.

Comment: no///all text returned from input

Comment: You mean, only the  copied bit?

Comment: YES only the copied bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
input.oncopy  = function(e) {
    var value = this.value.substring(this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd);
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxna8/)